# Exclude folder with sources which are built in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, unit-testing, resources, intellij-idea

I open maven project in Idea.
I store my files which are used for unit testing in folder \src\test\resources

But the issue is files which are used for testing are java-files.

Despite 'mvn package' skip this files, but when opening in Idea it tries to compile them.

**Is it possible to exclude this folder with java-files from sources to be compiled in Idea?**

I use IntelliJ Idea 9.0.3

Comment: Have you accepted it with the tick, or voted it up with the up arrow?

Comment: I voted, by SO does not allow to accept after very short period of time, it asked me to wait for 4 minutes and I will be allowed to accept

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

```
File -> Settings -> Compiler -> Excludes
```

Add your path to `Path` and select `Recursively`

Answer (score 0):

Sure, go into your Modules view, find the module in question, and set your `src/test` directory to `Exclude Sources`.

Comment: This will also exclude them as resources, and the maven plugin may just reset this.